# Is this a pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

A naive and hard to test implementation of a method could look like this

```
public void getFromDatabaseComputeAndStore(SomeType param) {
     Collection<Something> s = dao.retrieveSomethingFromDatabase(param);
     Collection<Other> o = dao.retrieveOtherFromDatabase(param);
     Result r = null;
     <do massive computation, call other methods, figure out what r should be>
     <based on s and o>
     dao.store(r);
}
```

Normally I'd refactor this into something like

```
public void getFromDatabaseComputeAndStore(SomeType param) {
     Computer computer = new Computer();
     Collection<Something> s = dao.retrieveFromDatabase(param);
     Collection<Other> o = dao.retrieveOtherFromDatabase(param);
     computer.setSomething(s);
     computer.setOther(o);
     computer.execute();
     Result r = computer.getResult();
     dao.store(r);
}
```

where the `Computer` class is the key. This class does not interact with databases or other external systems and has no side effects, eg it's purely functional. Given the same `somethings` and `others`, the `result` will always be the same.

So my question are:

- Is this a known pattern with a name
- What would be the common name of a class with the functionality of `Computer`

I've looked at the `Strategy`, `Mediator`, and `Command` patterns, but I don't feel they fit perfectly.

Comment: why cant you simply have a method which takes two arguments? Especially since you are not using multiple threads or getting any other advantage besides some neater code

Comment: It looks like a [Master/Worker pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8573733/829571). See also: http://blog.gigaspaces.com/2009/08/24/the-master-worker-pattern/.

Comment: Because, as I tried to show, the computations needed to calculate the results could be quite large and you might want to isolate it.

Comment: Errr, it is called refactoring. This is a style, not a pattern.

Comment: Or at the very least decoupling, since you're decoupling the `Computer` from having to know about the formatting, etc of DB results.

Answer (score 0):

Your Computer is a form of a Builder.

One use of a Builder is to allow complex construction of an object to be encapulated such that the client of the builder never has access to a partially constructed or invalid object.  You configure the Builder and then fetch the completed object from it.

Note that the GoF has a builder example that includes a polymorphic result.  That usage is common as well, but I don't feel it is strictly required.

.NET and Java have ample examples of both usages in their frameworks.